# What's the difference between BSP and MPI?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, graph-algorithm

What is the difference between BSP and MPI?

I know [Pregel's](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/large-scale-graph-computing-at-google.html) graph computation framework is based on BSP. Why didn't they use MPI directly or develop a framework based on MPI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bulk Synchronous Parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel) (BSP) is an abstract machine, like PRAM. Actions in BSP are "supersteps" that mix communication and computation with a barrier synchronization across all processes. BSP also famously has a cost model.

The [Message Passing Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (MPI) is a standard API for communication in distributed-memory parallel applications. There are numerous implementations of this API, both commercial and open source.

There are [some libraries](http://www.bsp-worldwide.org/) that *support* BSP-model communication, but there is no BSP standard API. So when the creators of Pregel say they are using BSP, they mean they are using asynchronous communication to schedule messages, followed by some sort of barrier. It is definitely possible to do this in MPI-2 using the remote-memory access ("one-sided communication") functions like `MPI_Put()`.

Comment: how can MPI-2 make MPI_Put() to do the remote-memory access? @chrisaycock

Comment: @xunzhang What do you mean? `MPI_Put()` is one of the remote-memory access functions in MPI-2. You don't have to *make it* do anything. Just read a book on MPI-2.